# MySQL user can not see the table that they have access

Tags: mysql

I have created the user on MySQL and grant SELECT access on some tables. I only want this user has SELECT access on these tables, nothing else. This is my query for creating the user and granting access:

```
create user 'test'@'localhost' identified by '123test';

grant select on APE.CertificationAttachment to 'test'@'localhost';
```

The problem is when I use this user login, I can not see anything under schema in Workbench. I try to login at other tools such as Dbeaver but the table and schema still don't show up. I tried to give schema privilege to the user, but that action will either give select access to all table or show the entire schema.

So my question is how should I do to make the users see the table and only these table that they have SELECT access to.

Comment: I just tested this. It should work fine. Even though  you can't see it, can you select from that table?

Comment: Is mysql-wokbench on the same (`localhost`) server? Because you can't access it from another **station** in this case

Comment: Also: 
`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test'@'localhost';` to see what MySQL has accepted

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I tested on another server and it worked fine. It might be the server setting issue even though I still don't know what case this.